# Как программно установить background из @mipmap/nameless (Java)

Tags: java, android

Я использовал это для  однообразного фона

```
View someView = findViewById(R.id.view);
                View root = someView.getRootView();
                root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
```

А теперь нужно именно отсюда вытащить фото

```
@mipmap/nameless
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   View someView = findViewById(R.id.view);
            View root = someView.getRootView();
            root.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.nameless);
```

вот источник

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484360/set-mipmap-image-as-linearlayout-background-programmatically